# PHP array element has value but is null

Tags: php

I run into a weird issue today. Here is the var dump of my array

[image]

And here is my code

```
 var_dump($file_line);
 var_dump($file_line['Name']);
```

Although the array has element "Name" and this element has value, var_dump the element gives NULL

[image]

I don't understand what happened. Can anyone help?
To reproduce the issue you need to have this csv lines

Name,Email,Financial Status,Paid at,Fulfillment Status,Fulfilled at,Accepts Marketing,Currency,Subtotal,Shipping,Taxes,Total,Discount Code,Discount Amount,Shipping Method,Created at,Lineitem quantity,Lineitem name,Lineitem price,Lineitem compare at price,Lineitem sku,Lineitem requires shipping,Lineitem taxable,Lineitem fulfillment status,Billing Name,Billing Street,Billing Address1,Billing Address2,Billing Company,Billing City,Billing Zip,Billing Province,Billing Country,Billing Phone,Shipping Name,Shipping Street,Shipping Address1,Shipping Address2,Shipping Company,Shipping City,Shipping Zip,Shipping Province,Shipping Country,Shipping Phone,Notes,Note Attributes,Cancelled at,Payment Method,Payment Reference,Refunded Amount,Vendor,Outstanding Balance,Employee,Location,Device ID,Id,Tags,Risk Level,Source,Lineitem discount,Tax 1 Name,Tax 1 Value,Tax 2 Name,Tax 2 Value,Tax 3 Name,Tax 3 Value,Tax 4 Name,Tax 4 Value,Tax 5 Name,Tax 5 Value,Phone

ughh12551,test,refunded,11/20/2017 11:15,unfulfilled,,no,USD,36.99,2.99,0,39.98,,0,Flat Rate,11/20/2017 11:15,1,Jessica Curry - 'So Let Us Melt: Official Soundtrack' [(Blue & Orange) Vinyl LP],36.99,0,BSR025LP,TRUE,TRUE,pending,Molly Vu,2933 Fairmont Street,2933 Fairmont Street,,,Falls Church,'22042,VA,US,,Molly Vu,2933 Fairmont Street,2933 Fairmont Street,,,Falls Church,'22042,VA,US,,11/20/17: Voided at customer's request.,,11/20/2017 11:39,PayPal Payflow Pro,c165457068047.1,39.98,Black Screen Records,0,,,,1.04859E+11,,Low,web,0,,,,,,,,,,,

Then my complete code is

```
$header = NULL;
$data = array();

$files = array(
'orders_export_2.csv',
);

foreach ($files as $file) {
if (($handle = fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . '/ughh/' . $file, 'r')) !== FALSE) 
{
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if (!$header) {
            $header = $row;
        } else {
            $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
 }
 }

foreach ($data as $key => $file_line) {
    var_dump($file_line);
    print_r($file_line);
    var_dump($file_line['Name']);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `Name` has an unprintable character in it.

Comment: Can you post var_dump full data, I think it's nested in array, and you're trying to access it directly.

Comment: Here is the screenshot of print_r. 'Name' element is totally fine. There is no nested array https://www.screencast.com/t/YFJSZAvedqgL

Comment: Can you post a code snippet sufficient to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Also, if you don't already have full error reporting enabled, turning it on might help troubleshoot: `error_reporting(E_ALL)` (and `ini_set('display_errors', true)` if you don't already have error display enabled).

Comment: Error reporting is E_ALL and there is no error in error_log.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. The output from `var_dump($file_line['Name'])` should be `string(9) "ughh12551"` (that's what it was for me when I ran this code). I'm not sure why your screenshot shows a filename and line number. I would restart your web server just in case you have some sort of PHP caching enabled; also check the file encoding.

Comment: I have ran you code and it works ok. 
I'm shure you have extra "\r\n" in you file.
So you are looking to whole array by one row, but to one element by another empty row.